# Does @see can be use to reference function by name?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I know that it can point to a method, but if I want to reference a function from other file?

E.g:

```
/**
 * @see fn_name()
 */
```

is ok?

and can I use this tag inside other function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/see.html):

> The *@see* tag can be used to define a reference to other **Structural Elements** or to an URI.

so yes, you can use `@see` to make reference to other method.